# The gif saved in Photoshop freezes mid play

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, adobe-after-effects

The gif saved in Photoshop freezes mid play. Does not matter where I upload it. You can see it here: http://www.peneroyal.com/tmp/freeze.gif

The freeze does not happen in the Photoshop preview.

The procedure of making that gif is:
After Effects
->
Rendering sequence of tiffs
->
Making the gif in Photoshop (save for web).
->
The gif breaks.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

It's not freezing mid play. It seems that older versions of Photoshop have a **limit of 500 frames** for Saved for Web GIF. Which, to be honest, is a lot of frames, since GIFs are not really suitable for video, they are meant for much shorter animations.

You could solve by updating your software, I added 100+ frames to your GIF then exporting with CS6 and it worked fine.

Either you reduce the number of frames to be exported in your animation (for example, instead of 30fps use 15fps) or if that's not enough and you really have to export that many frames, choose a different format according to the purpose.

Comment: It's not merely "old versions" here. CC2017 shows the same 500 frame limitation on my system :) Note you only see the frames truncated in the saved file, not in an open file you just saved. You have to reopen the saved .gif to see it only has 500 frames.

Comment: at first I thought it was an ongoing limitation, but then I tried exporting a longer gif here and it worked... I open the new gif and all the frames are there

Comment: Are you sure? Did you reopen the gif you exported and check? Things *appear* to export fine... but the actual file will only have 500 frames max.

Comment: I did, you can see it here http://imgur.com/4BZRnkV (the animation is truncated, but the frames are all there). I just pasted more frames at the end and exported, worked fine (although my PS just crashed)

Comment: hmm.. interesting. I only get 500 frames in CC2017 here when I save. But I do see 600 frames in your file. Time to trash SFW prefs :)

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has a **limit of 500 frames** for **importing a video file**. The video import merely **stops** after 500 frames.

If your video is **longer than 500 frames**, you'll need to import frames 1-500 into one Photoshop document, then import frames 501+ into a *different* Photoshop document. And then you can simply move the video layers to the same Photoshop file. Photoshop itself doesn't contain a limit to the frame count, it's the video import feature which contains this limitation.